# Firebase Analytics StreamView odd behaviour

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-analytics

When using [DebugView](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/debugview) in Firebase, everything works perfectly.  I've set up custom events in Firebase Analytics, for example, to fire when I press the 'Share' Button - and these events come through pretty much within 10 seconds or so of pressing the Share button in my app.

I've set these up like so:

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString(Param.ITEM_ID, "Share");
bundle.putString(Param.CONTENT_TYPE, "ShareAppLink"); //define these here to differentiate between different things that can be shared
mFirebaseAnalytics.logEvent(Event.SHARE, bundle);
```

Now, the problem is that when I go into [SteamView](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7229836?hl=en), I'm not seeing what I expect to see...

If I fire off random events (including hitting the Share button as described above), basically, nothing happens.  Over the course of 40 minutes or so, I get nothing shown in the timeline.  However, as soon as I uninstall the app from the device, all the events come through at once... here is a screengrab to show what I mean:

[image]

The 'first_open' even *does* come through at the correct time.

This device was previously registered as a debug device (for DebugView), but it has been 'de-registered' (and DebugView now shows 0 devices as expected). This is a signed APK that I'm testing with StreamView and I've tested this on 2 physical devices with the same results.

Has anyone come across problems like this with Firebase StreamView?  Am I doing something wrong or misunderstanding how it works?

Comment: This is not an expected behavior. Please send a request to Firebase Support https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/ pointing to this post and they shall look into it.

Comment: When not in debug mode, Firebase Analytics uploads events on a roughly one-hour cycle.  When you open an app for the first time it will tend to send the first open event within 15 seconds, but after that unless you enable debug mode on that device you will have to wait an hour for the next batch of events.

Comment: facing the same issue. Any workaround??

Comment: Kind of @sJy... I contacted Firebase support and they confirmed that this **is** expected behaviour. The events are collected up on the users device and then sent off in one batch at a specific time or after a specific event is triggered (like uninstalling the app). This is to prevent the users' device having to constantly send small pieces of data.